# What is this Red Line on chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, caching, browser, web-inspector

[image]

My website load is slow, everything is added to the Load time. However, I see a vertical Red Line when I check eBay, Amazon, slickdeal.

In the screenshot, you will see the red line stops at 5.62s and everything that loads after that line does not count as part of load time.

Does anyone know why it is like this? How is it that the tools show that the load time was done at 5.62s, but things did still load after this red line.

Comment: I'd suggest reading https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/ domcontent vs load state are well documented on the internet already.

Answer (score 2):

The red line is the Window's `load` event.  That is, when all of the page's resources have loaded and are displayed, this event fires.

That doesn't prevent scripts on the page from loading stuff afterwards.  Many developers actually subscribe to this event and others like it to then start loading things as a micro-optimization.  Usually, such optimizations are ill-advised and don't do anything useful.  (Some believe having a faster `load` event triggering is an SEO tactic, when really it often hurts the user experience, which hurts their traffic more.  Others think that seeing numbers go down in their analytics software is a good thing, when really they're just gathering garbage data.)

Comment: but hwut about muh TTFB?

Comment: @Sammitch Ha!  :-D